# How to change value of module_param parameter in the device driver?

Tags: linux-device-driver

I wrote a simple program for taking a value through command line into my driver. I used `module_param()` for this and gave permission argument, i.e third arg of `module_param()`, as S_IWUSR.
This I guess would allow user to modify the value of that parameter once driver is loaded in the kernel. I tried to modify the value of that parameter by:

```sh
echo 1 > /sys/module/ghost/parameters/num
```

But this shows me *Permission denied* error every time I try to do this, even when I execute the command with `sudo`. I also tried changing permission in `module_param()` to `0770` but still was not able to change the parameter value. Is there a way to change the value of parameter passed while inserting the driver ? Why does the above command shows permission denied, even if I run as sudo ?

After the answer of @Ian Abott I am to change the value of the parameter. Now I tried to define a callback function to notify me any changes in the value of that parameter while my driver is loaded. Here is the code

```
  #include"headers.h"
#include"declarations.h"

static int my_set(const char *val, const struct kernel_param *kp)
{
    int n = 0, ret;
    ret = kstrtoint(val,10,&n);                                                     // Kernel function to convert string to integer
    if (ret !=0 || n > 10) {
        return -EINVAL;
    }   
    printk(KERN_ALERT "my-set function running\n");
    return param_set_int(val,kp);
}

static const struct kernel_param_ops param_ops = { 
    .set    = my_set,
    .get    = param_get_int,
};


module_param(num,int,0600);

static char *name = "hello";
module_param(name,charp,0770);

static int __init init_func(void)
{
    int i;
    module_param_cb(callBack, &param_ops, &num, 0770);
    printk(KERN_INFO "Value of num is %d\n",num);
    for( i=0; i<num; i++) 
    {   
        printk(KERN_INFO "%s\n", name);
    }   
    return 0;
}

static void __exit exit_func(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Value of num is %d\n",num);
    printk(KERN_ALERT "Module removed successfully\n");

}


module_init(init_func);
module_exit(exit_func);
```

But it doesn't seem to work because my_set function never runs, even if I change the value. My doubt is
1) Is this correct way to implement callback function for the parameter?
2) What is significance of first argument to the function module_param_cb?

Comment: hi and welcome to StackOverflow!

please [edit] your question to clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need.

as it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If you need to use **sudo**, then `sudo echo 1 > /sys/module/ghost/parameters/num` wouldn't work because only the `echo 1` would be run under **sudo** and the `>` redirection would be done as the original user. The usual way around that is `sudo sh -c "echo 1 > /sys/module/ghost/parameters/num"`.

Comment: @Ian Abbott Thanks a lot! It worked. I have few more questions. 1) Can we have check on the value that we enter during inserting the driver, like if the value is within some range or not ?. 2)  Is there a way to know in my driver, like a callback function, that the value of the parameter has changed ?

Comment: @atul_pant 1) No, the module code needs to check the value. 2) No.

Comment: @IanAbbot, but what about `module_param_cb()`? It seems 2) Yes.

Comment: @0andriy Yes, that will work, thanks.

Comment: @0andriy Please can look the question again. I have added new information